# How to retrieve array of contents in a range of cells from search criteria in excel

Tags: excel, search

Pls share your ideas how to resolve this scenario in excel. If possible no VBA.

I need to search a specific string from a range of cells; if match, return each  contents by representing it as 1. Otherwise, check if cell is empty return 0 and retrieve the value of each cells if not.

Formula currently like:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text",'Sheet 1 of4'!$H$50:$GE$50)),1,IF(ISBLANK('Sheet 1 of4'!$H$50:$GE$50),0, this part here is my problem))
```

Comment: At a minimum, sample data together with expected results is needed. Add what you've come up with so far (working or not). I think I can speak for a number of users when I say that I can learn more from data and formulas than trying to decipher clues from a narrative.

Comment: I come up something like this, the only problem was I couldn't retrieve the contents of every cells where 1 & 2 conditions wasn't meet.                =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text",'Sheet 1 of4'!$H$50:$GE$50)),1,IF(ISBLANK('Sheet 1 of4'!$H$50:$GE$50),0, this part here is my problem))

Comment: I'm not sure if that formula was started right at the beginning.

Comment: So if the text is found in any of the 180 cells in H50:GE50 return a **1**. If all 180 cells in H50:GE50 are blank then return a 0. Otherwise concatenate all 180 cells and return that. Is that what is intended to happen?

Comment: If text found in any of those cells it must return an array of. 1s Likewise, if it is blank except it will return an array of 0s. If none of these two conditions are meet, return an array of what was the value of those cells.

Comment: You could really use a 'helper' cell that concatenates all of the 180 potential values together. Could GF50 be used? What cell is the original formula destined for?

Comment: actually, i never used any other cell since i directly feed those returned values in excel chart. The 1st condition =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text",'Sheet 1 of4'!$H$50:$GE$50)),1...... excel plot those 1s in the chart as well as the 2nd condition whose cells  are empty. The thing is, i want to plot also those values that doesnt fall on to those two conditions (this value is an integer number).